# What's a good way to handle flash notifications in meteor (with meteor-router)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using [meteor](http://meteor.com) along with [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) for client and server side routing. I'm wondering what a good way to handle site notifications, specifically "flash" type ones.

In the global layout.html I can have a handlebars output a message if a "message" session variable is set, but the message shouldn't stick around once the app is routed to a new url with `Meteor.Router.to()`.

What's a good solution to having "flash" notifications? Or, how can I automatically clear a session variable after routing to a new URL.

layout.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor App</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> global-layout}}
</body>

<template name="global-layout">
   {{#if message}}
      <div class="message">{{message}}</div>
   {{/if}}
   {{renderPage}}
</template>
```

then in layout.js

```
Template['global-layout'].message = function () {
  return Session.get('message');
};
```

Comment: I found [this pull request](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/pull/25) and [this repo](https://github.com/egtann/meteor-router), which appears to be the beginning of a solution, but there isn't documentation on displaying the notifications.

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer, so it can be voted and commented upon.

Comment: Ah that's just it. I haven't been able to get anything to work yet. That repo seems to have the right intent, but it doesn't show how to put the notifications on the template. I'll continue poking around with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using a `Meteor.Router.filter` for this. This filter will be applied to all routes, therefore all flashes will be cleared on all url changes.

**routes.js**

```
Meteor.Router.filters({
  // clearSeenMessages filter clears all seen messages. 
  // This filters is applied to all pages 
  clearSeenMessages: function (page) {
    flash.clear();
    return page;
  },
});

// applies to all pages
Meteor.Router.filter('clearSeenMessages');
```

Here's the rest of the implementaion, aspects were borrowed from [telesc.pe](http://telesc.pe)

**client/views/flashes/flash_item.html**

```
    <template name="flashItem">
      {{#if show}}
        <div class="alert-box {{type}}">
          {{message}}
          <a class="close"  href="">&times;</a>
        </div>
      {{/if}}
    </template>
```

**client/views/flashes/flash_item.js**

```
// When the template is first created
Template.flashItem.created = function () {
  // Get the ID of the messsage
  var id = this.data._id;
  Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
    // mark the flash as "seen" after 100 milliseconds
    flash.Flashes.update(id, {$set: {seen: true}});
  }, 100);
}
```

**client/views/flashes/flashes.html**

```
<template name="flashes">
  {{#each flashes}}
    {{> flashItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**client/views/flashes/flashes.js**

```
Template.flashes.flashes = function () {
  return flash.Flashes.find();
}
```

**client/views/app.html**

```
<body>
  <!-- add the flashes somewhere in the body -->
  {{> flashes}}
</body>
```

**client/lib/flashes.js**

```
// flashes provides an api for temporary flash messages stored in a
// client only collecion
var flash = flash || {};

(function (argument) {
  // Client only collection
  flash.Flashes = new Meteor.Collection(null);

  // create given a message and optional type creates a Flash message.
  flash.create = function (message, type) {
    type = (typeof type === 'undefined') ? 'error' : type;
    // Store errors in the 'Errors' local collection
    flash.Flashes.insert({message: message, type: type, seen: false, show: true});
  };

  // error is a helper function for creating error messages
  flash.error = function (message) {
    return flash.create(message, 'error');
  };

  // success is a helper function for creating success messages
  flash.success = function (message) {
    return flash.create(message, 'success');
  };

  // info is a helper function for creating info messages
  flash.info = function (message) {
    return flash.create(message, 'info');
  };

  // clear hides viewed message
  flash.clear = function () {
    flash.Flashes.update({seen: true}, {$set: {show: false}}, {multi: true});
  };
})();
```

#### Usage

```
flash.success('This is a success message');
flash.error('This is a error message');
flash.info('This is a info message');
```

Comment: Aha, using filters for it is pretty clever, and the trick is what you did to mark them as seen.

Comment: @Diogenes, I can't take credit for the 'seen' trick that comes from [telesc.pe](http://telesc.pe). The [source](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope) has quite a few useful techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [router-with-flash](https://github.com/egtann/meteor-router) package available on [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.meteor.com/) to handle flash notifications. If you use meteorite (which you should), you can do `mrt add router-with-flash` in the root directory of your project. Then, to display an alert you need to -

```
Meteor.Router.to("/", { alert: "Some alert..." });
Meteor.Router.notification("alert");
```

This will display the alert until the next call to `Meteor.Router.to()`.

Comment: But the goal is to have the notification (of success, alert, or error type, perhaps) appear and then automatically disappear at the next .to() call. Manually setting that session variable to null means every possible view you could switch to has to do it.

Comment: Changed the answer after I found the [router-with-flash](https://github.com/egtann/meteor-router) package on [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.meteor.com).

Comment: I had found that earlier (see my comment on the question), but couldn't figure out how those notifications are supposed to be displayed in a template.